# IntelliJ Plugin change code style of Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, intellij-plugin

I am developing a custom IntelliJ plugin but I am having a few problems changing the default code style of Java. I checked the documentation but the only thing I could find were steps on how to create a custom code style for a custom language.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I tried using `langCodeStyleSettingsProvider` and giving it a class that extends the `JavaLanguageCodeStyleSettingsProvider` but the result was that in the settings windows, two Java tabs are showing with the same settings.